# Graphics2D encountered many duplicate parameters

Tags: java, graphics2d

I am using this code to draw a small image in the upper right corner. But it seems the parameters are duplicates. I just started using the Graphics2D class and I think I did it the wrong way. How should I fix it?

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    g2d.setPaint(new TexturePaint(slate, new Rectangle(getWidth()/3,20,this.getWidth()*3/5, 
    this.getHeight()/8)));
    g2d.fillRect(getWidth()/3, 20, this.getWidth()*3/5, this.getHeight()/8);
}
```

[image]

Comment: What should it look like? Do you get any errors?

Comment: Call `super.paintComponent(g);`. For more help post [mre].

Comment: Below is the result of the code. It did not encounter an error, but it does not appear to be optimal. All parameters in `setPaint()` overlap with `fillRect()`

Comment: @c0der  `super.paintComponent(g)` has been called